# Static build in Visual Studio c++?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm using a certain lib (libeay32). How can I statically build it into my exe so separate .dll is not needed?
Also, is it possible to do the same for vc++ runtime?

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the headers, an import .lib  and the DLL, I don't know if it can be done.

If you have the full source code for the *libeay32* library, you could change the general build options from *dynamic library* to *static library*, and then add it as a library file to your exe.